# What is "review" in context of locked/deleted?

Tags: support, wording

Below the body of the locked/deleted post you can see a message:

> [image: comments not allowed]

What does "reviews" mean in this context?

Comment: According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190536/change-deleted-locked-posts-reviews-to-something-more-readable), it is simply a horribly constructed sentence. It is supposed to mean "posts or reviews which are either deleted or locked", rather than "deleted posts, locked posts or reviews", I think. (A review obviously just being a task from one of the queues on `/review`, e.g. a First Post)

Comment: @Aurora0001 but I can add a comment on posts via review queues.

Comment: Yes, I know. It's only **deleted or locked reviews** that cannot be commented on, which is what I was trying to point out. It's not at all clear though; I think it probably should just be rewritten to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Aurora0001 I still can't understand how I can comment on **review**. Even in review mode I comment on the **post**, and comment belongs to the post, not to a review.

Comment: I think that what @Aurora is trying to say is that review leads to deletion of posts, and then you can't comment on those posts. Another option though, is that in the beginning comments were not available on reviews, and were added only later, but the wording was simply not changed since then.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, a "deleted review" means review item where the relevant post has been deleted.

Normally, when the post is not deleted, you can add comments directly from the review item, however when it's deleted it's not possible anymore, and the message explains it. Since you're still in review, it fits.

<sub>[Example for a "deleted" review item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/85985)</sub>

Comment: Still not clear for me why do we need "review" word here - comments owned by post (question or answer), not by something called "review".