# Text overlapping in comment in iOS

Tags: bug, comments, design, ios

Text in the [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294531/what-is-review-in-context-of-locked-deleted#comment955322_294532) formated as code overlaps with text (`@` symbol) in previous line:

> [image: Overlapped @]

Reproduced on iOS only: Chrome (57.0.2987.137), Safari.

- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.1 (Build 14E304)

Comment: Is that on the full site?

Comment: @Cai yep. On mobile `@` y-pos is [slightly upper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdkaS.jpg).

Comment: Yeh thought so. The answer to bugs when viewing the full site on mobile are generally "tough, use the mobile view" (they aren't [officially supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/307988)). Font sizes especially are all over the place.

Comment: @Cai should I still need to use mobile site being on iPad Pro 12.9"? :)