# Should we burninate the [ios] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Currently, [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) is used by only 30 questions on Meta Stack Exchange.

[Looking at the tagged questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios), nearly all of them would easily fit under [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app) (1,140 questions) or [mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web) (782 questions), which have arguably supplanted the tag.

Should [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) be burninated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would not recommend to burninate [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) tag because some issues could affect only iOS devices without using app or mobile web. E.g. my recent bug report: [Text overlapping in comment in iOS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294549/339911)

Comment: Fair point. I suppose there are some cases where the tag could be useful