# Can we be more clear why you can't comment on certain posts?

Tags: feature-request, comments, review, user-experience, locked

When you look at deleted/locked/review question's or answer's comment area (like [the best answer ever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454)) you get to see this very vague message:

[image: comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews]
This message tells me **so** little. How hard is it to replace this message with this:

> Comments are disabled on *{reason}* *{post_type}*.

Where `{reason}` is the reason (`locked` or `deleted`), and `{post_type}` is the type of the post (`questions`, `answers`, or `reviews`).

This would turn in to:

> Comments are disabled on locked answers

That is a lot better than this, which tells me nothing (and is bad grammer):

> comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews

Just see for yourself:

[image: Comments are disabled on locked answers]
<sup>You can see it without the circle and text [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyvx2.png).</sup>

All of this would not affect performance because the site already tells us if something is locked/deleted/review, just in a not helpful place that you have to look at.

Can we please make these messages more clear?

Comment: related, if not a duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190536/change-deleted-locked-posts-reviews-to-something-more-readable although we might consider closing the other way around as this question seems more complete.

Comment: @rene I would say related, as that question is just complaining about readability.

Comment: It is fairly obvious that is a locked post. It says "locked by Marc Gravell" right there.

Comment: @RoryAlsop my point is that it would be nice to not have the message be vague, not that it is a feature that is **highly needed**. I just don't like how the message doesn't tell you anything helpful in it of itself.

Comment: @EthanK - Except the gray text specifically indicates comments are disabled on locked questions.

Comment: I'm confused about what's confusing about the message. It doesn't explicitly tell you which of the reasons applies, but I think it should be obvious to see if you're looking at a deleted answer or locked Q&A.

Comment: @TheWanderer It is obvious. I just don’t like how the message itself doesn’t tell you anything.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "are" is omitted because it's supposed to be in headline style, which regularly skips some verbs : https://english.stackexchange.com/q/198869/121385

Comment: @EthanK it tells you that you can't comment. What more could it say? Your question seems to be complaining that it's too generic, but then you admit that it's perfectly obvious how it applies.

Comment: Partial explanation: [Comments are used to explain the reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158439/282094) **if** it is decided to offer a better reason than what one might guess from the circumstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, i think it's clear enough...

Saying:

> comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews

Because deleted posts, and locked posts, and reviews, are all possibilities of the reason, so why it only needs to say one, or alternate?

And i think this good grammar, see:

> comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews

Saying "comments disabled on a / b / c"

That's okay grammar.

So i think it should stay like now.

**Edit:**

i humanly think:

> comments disabled..

is okay grammar, it's useful for saving space, and "are" to put in between won't make any real differences, and i searched, it seems to be valid English.

Comment: I meant it should be “comments **are** disabled on...” when I said bad grammer.